# Does a Tool for the analyzation of JBoss log files exist?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, log-analysis

I have a JBoss 6 Server running which generates a big log file.

Does a tool exist, which allows me to analyse the log file (How often did a specific error occur? When did it occur? How many INFO / WARNING / ERROR messages are there, ...)?

I've heard of [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j), but it seems as if it would only allow me to set up a configuration for logging options. Am I right?

If no GUI tools, do you know a library/module/scripts for Python/PHP which helps me to parse the log file?

Comment: The project Chainsaw has ben changed home site to http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/) and [Log Parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274)